# How to create a voice pitch meter/analyzer in AS3/Flex?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

AS3 or Flex : How to create a voice pitch meter/analyzer? Is it possible?

How to create voice pitch analyzer on flex or AS3? do you have any idea? or is there any software like this that can be used on a web site?

Comment: Be more specific in your question, do your own research.

Comment: This question seems too broad. Please ask a new question that is more specific.

Comment: kindly read the question again... are you guys familiar with  the voice pitch? i  need an analyzer for a voice pitch.. example if i input a high pitch the bar(animation) will go up or if it  is low the bar will go down. thanks for your respond

Comment: @Noki Flores Many "How do I..." questions are perceived as "Please do my work for me."  Nothing in your question explains what you have tried; what issues you've run into; nor why you're having trouble solving them.  It makes people think you haven't tried anything yet.  That is most likely why J_A_X and David felt this question was too broad.

Comment: Noki I agree with everyone else here. Your question is to broad and instead of adding to your question in the comments please edit your question and add it there. But in any case I have never seen a pitch-o-meter anywhere.

Comment: yeah sorry guys.. i can't post the code that i've started because it all end up just a basic voice analyzer anyway thanks The_asMAn i've always searching for that pitch analyzer but ive never seen one..  www.Flextras.com thanks for your advice i will  do it the next time that i will post a question

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a stab at this... maybe this article on analyzing sound in AS3 might be helpful.

[Another computeSpectrum() Example](http://www.todaycreate.com/2009/01/17/another-computespectrum-example)

This is the visual part of the analysis. It would theoretically take in any Sound data. The part of your app would be file I/O getting into a sound object that would work with this.

Here's another article

[Tutorial – Spectrum analyzer with AS3](http://flashenabled.wordpress.com/2007/06/01/tutorial-spectrum-analyzer-with-as3/)

Comment: Thanks for the respond mark lapasa i already have the first link i just want to know what is the  bar for the pitch tone there? do you have any idea or it is not in that basicAnalyzer?.. i already check the other link and i think i can use it. thanks a lot!

Comment: From what I have heard and seen, computeSpectrum is EXTREMELY slow, sometimes as much as 2-3 seconds off, in case of high quality and resolutions.